# Substring with specific characters in html, php

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to perform a substring operation by specific characters.
For example, I have a variable named code consisting data of "EX00001", "A00012".

And I would like to perform a substring to get only the numeric part so that I can perform addition operation to it.

```
"EX00001"
I would like to get only 1.

"A00012"
I would like to get only 12.
```

I am able to sub string by "EX" and "A" only.
How can I go about doing it to substring by alphabet and all the 0.

As the code can be "EX00001", "EX00122", "EX01254", etc.

```
 <script>

  var str=code;
  document.write(str.substring(2,7));

   </script>
```

Comment: Ummm, that's JavaScript, Not PHP as tagged

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript:

```js
document.write(str.replace(/^[a-z0]+/i, ''));
```

For PHP, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.preg-replace.php):

```php
echo preg_replace('/^[a-z0]+/i', '', 'EX000001');
```

Answer (score 0):

for PHP version 5.2 and above

you can use:

> filter_var('EX00001', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

below 5 version

> preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", "EX00001");